# Google drive api not recognising permissions

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a shared folder with three google accounts and a website were we can upload files to this shared folder using the google drive api. With two of the accounts this works perfectly, but with the third account a 404 error is received when making the request:

"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B2rwdIN0_q3JTy05Q3hUemJrQ3M/permissions"

This error I would receive if a person tries to loggin but has no permission to the folder. I would think there is something wrong with the permissions of this 3rd account, but when performing the request logged in as the third account and using the https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/list and https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/get using the fileID specified above. I do get a 200 response! This permission is 07821925381698322814, which I can obtain running the same request with the other accounts.

So I have no idea what is wrong. Could it be that these is only a maximum of 2 accounts or something like that? Should you want to see the code, see the javascript source of http://krs.solar/bonnetjes.

EDIT:

It only works with one account, mine. I am the developer, or the one with the API key and such. Do i have to activate something so that non developers can make requests?

[image: Screenshot with user logged in google drive web interface]

Comment: this is the error, which is normal should an account not have a permission to write in that folder, what it DOES have. I am not able to upload file from our created interface, obtain the same response. "{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: 0B2rwdIN0_q3JTy05Q3hUemJrQ3M.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fileId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: 0B2rwdIN0_q3JTy05Q3hUemJrQ3M."
 }
}
"

Comment: Does it happen if you sign in first before making the request?

Comment: Request happens in "updateSigninStatus". As mentioned before, I works fine with the other accounts that have access

function initClient(){
        gapi.client.init({
          discoveryDocs:DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          clientId:CLIENT_ID,
          apiKey:API-KEY,
          scope:SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        });
      }